# Product version for VS2010 projects

Tags: .net, version, visual-studio-2010

When I create a new project of any kind (winforms app/classlib ..) using VS2010 beta2, all the projects have ProductVersion field set to 8.0.30703. I was expecting it to be something like 10.0.21006.1. Is this version so because its in beta or is there something wrong with the version that is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be an issue with VS 2010 Beta. It may be present in other project templates, but for sure known in [C# console application/class library project templates](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=514813).